# "Invalid sqlstate code sqlstate 'ex_invalid_t' ^" error in user defined exception in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql-9.5

When I use a user defined exception in PostgreSQL like

```
being
if(any condition) then
raise exception using errcode='ex_invalid_t';
end if;

exception
when sqlstate 'ex_invalid_t' then
raise notice or any code
end;
```

I get an error:

> Invalid sqlstate code sqlstate 'ex_invalid_t' ^

What alternatives to user defined exceptions are there in PostgreSQL?

Answer (score 0):

here is working sample:

custom exception:

```
t=# create function s163() returns void as
$$
begin
raise exception '%','boom!';
end;
$$ language plpgsql
;
```

consuming:

```
t=# do
$$
declare
 _t text;
begin
  perform s163();
  exception when SQLSTATE 'P0001' then raise info '%',SQLERRM;
end;
$$
;
INFO:  boom!
DO
Time: 0.307 ms
```